# SHA - 2 (256) Как происходит сжатие?

Tags: sha256

Не могу понять как и в каком месте в алгоритме, происходит сжатие 512 бит в 256.

1. Добавляем единицу к сообщению
2. Заполняем нулями пространство до 512 бит.
3. Записываем длину вводного сообщения в место младших нулей, записанных на шаге два.
   Итого, на вводе мешалки, 512 бит.
   Константы, мешаем с подготовленными выше 512 битами (цикл сжатия). На выходе получаем 256 бит? Как?

Псевдокод сообщает: "сообщение обрабатывается последовательными порциями по 512 бит."
Далее, из них формируется еще 1536 бит (48 дополнительных слов). Потом все перемешивается. Не могу увидеть место, где обработанные куски соединяются, то есть если сообщение влазит в один кусок 512 бит, то проблемы нет, но если сообщение разбито на несколько, результат обработки каждого должен где-то соединяться с предыдущими. Это и есть: "Добавить полученные значения к ранее вычисленному результату: h0 := h0 + a
h1 := h1 + b ..."? Или я не туда понимаю?

Comment: Ну так вы распишите 3 шаг по действиям. А то получается какой-то остаток совы.

Comment: Что значит как? Посмотрите [описание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#SHA-256).  512-битный блок преобразуется в массив из шестнадцати 32-битных слов. Это входные данные для «мешалки». Далее данный массив обрабатывается по специальному алгоритму с активным использованием битовых операций и магических констант. Результат работы «мешалки» — восемь 32-битных слов, т.е 8 * 32 = 256 бит.

Comment: В описании по приведённой ссылке результат алгоритма хранится в восьми 32-битных переменных с именами `a`, `b`, ..., `h`.

Comment: Я пытаюсь увидеть в каком именно месте: Σ0 := (a rotr 2) xor (a rotr 13) xor (a rotr 22)
        Ma := (a and b) xor (a and c) xor (b and c)
        t2 := Σ0 + Ma
        Σ1 := (e rotr 6) xor (e rotr 11) xor (e rotr 25)
        Ch := (e and f) xor ((not e) and g)
        t1 := h + Σ1 + Ch + k[i] + w[i] - 16 входящих слов, превращаются в 8 выходящих. Какая именно битовая операция теряет биты? Из того, что я вижу, мне не видно что происходит потеря. Сколько в битовую операцию входит, столько же выходит, но это не так и я пытаюсь понять где.

Comment: Ну, вот, например: `e := d + t1` из двух 32-битных переменных сделали одну 32-битную переменную. Чем вам не преобразование 64 бита в 32 бита?